# Map circle markers unique content onclick

Tags: javascript, json, onclick, leaflet

I'm trying to give each marker/shape on leaflet different information for `onClick`. The data I'm using is from a JSON array filled with objects.

The code I used to do this is:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([43.16556,  -77.61139], 13);

var OpenStreetMap_DE = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.de/tiles/osmde/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy;>'
}).addTo(map);

//Adding a circle. (point[long,Lat], radius in meters

// Saving for later :-)
// var zip = "/javascripts/zcta5.json",
// hsa = "/javascripts/hsa.json";

var host = new Array();
var temp;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$.getJSON("/allHospitals",function(data,status){
    var color;
    var thefill;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        temp = data[i];
        if (temp.name === "rgh") {
            color = '#FF9755';
            thefill = '#009666';
        } else if (temp.name === "strong") {
            color = '#FFE03A';
            thefill = '#7C83FF';
        }
        host.push(L.circle(data[i].lnglat, data[i].pplNum/2, {
        color: color,
        fillColor: thefill,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        weight:3
        }));
        host[i].on("click", onClick);
        host[i].addTo(map);


    }
});

var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg"),
g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");

function onOver(e){

}

function onClick (e) {
    console.log(temp);
}
```

It returns the last entry in the json file. How can I just make this work?

Answer (score 0):

```
function onClick (e) {
    console.log(temp);
}
```

You want to be looking at e not temp.  e is what was clicked, temp is just leftover from the loop above.

Comment: I've tried this. All it does is print the last `data` object.

Comment: console.log(e) not temp?

Comment: That only gives me click information. I personally don't need to display that.

Comment: (this) should give you the thing that was clicked